# can someone send me a step by step tutorial on ASP.NET Login module

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, authentication

i am really new to ASP.NET, i am currently using Visual Studio 2015, it has a fixed template on Log In forms, but  cant figure it how. how it works or how will i do it. i would want to have validating users, and the master pages has the "Hello, " label and a "[Log Out]" function beside it. i cant find a decent post about a step by step tutorial on how to make a Log In page. thanks!

how does this work?

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a>
```

and this?

```
<asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
```

and this is in the LogIn aspx.cs

```
//RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register";
        //// Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
        ////ForgotPasswordHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Forgot";
        //OpenAuthLogin.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        //var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        //{
        //    RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
        //}
//protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    if (IsValid)
    //    {
    //        // Validate the user password
    //        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    //        var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

    //        // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
    //        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    //        var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

    //        switch (result)
    //        {
    //            case SignInStatus.Success:
    //                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
    //                break;
    //            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
    //                Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
    //                break;
    //            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
    //                Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}", 
    //                                                Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
    //                                                RememberMe.Checked),
    //                                  true);
    //                break;
    //            case SignInStatus.Failure:
    //            default:
    //                FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
    //                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    //                break;
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
```

Comment: Step by step tutorials are out of scope of SO.

Comment: oh i mean can someone give me a link to a step by step procedure?

Comment: isn't Google the place you should go? Why bother others?

Comment: @LexLi SO has a very good community, i asked here because someone can help me here.

Comment: it is a good community for great questions. Check its FAQ to see which are the great questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/simple-login-project-in-Asp-Net/

Hope this will help you.